# Print ArrayList of Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I created an ArrayList of arrays, but I don't know how to print them.
Here's what I am trying to do:

```
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<aArray.length-1; i++){
        exp=new int[100];
        if (Character.isDigit(aArray[i])){
            if(Character.isDigit(aArray[i])==true &&  aArray[i-1]=='-'){
                exp[j]=Character.getNumericValue(-(aArray[i]));
            }
            else{
                exp[j]=Character.getNumericValue(aArray[i]);
            }
            System.out.print(exp[j]);

            j++;   
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    list.add(exp);
}
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i)[i]);
}
```

All I get is 5 zeros. What am I missing? Practically, I read a .txt file in my program, and all I want to do, is seperate and write the numbers of each in the exp[] arrays and then save them in list (ArrayList of Arrays).

Comment: `System.out.println(list.get(i)[i]);` with this, you only print the `i`th index of the `i`th array. If you want to print something twodimensional, you normally need two `for` loops.

Comment: yes this i know that this is wrong, but it couldn't be helped..
all i get is zeros, when the exp array contains 0,1,-1.

Comment: aArray, is the array that contains the numbers, but also contains commas, and other characters like "{" or "[" etc.

Comment: Because i did
     for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(0)[i]);
     }  
And it works... Because the list has one element only, but the array inside the list dont... So i changed the 'get(i)' to get(0)

Comment: And i used to test: char[] aArray={'a','2','3','4','e'};

Comment: You need to provide the complete code. Specifically, you should include the declaration and initialization of all of your variables. Parenthetically, I would strongly suggest choosing better variable names (e.g. aArray doesn't tell me anything about what the array is supposed to represent or contain) to make the code a little more readable.

Comment: the other code is just reading a .txt file.
as for aArray, I named it like that, because I won't need it in the future.
did anyone come up with an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add a for loop to go through each array in the list too:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    int[] tmp = list.get(i);
    for (int j=0; j<tmp.length; j++) {
         System.out.println(tmp[j]);
    }
}
```

edit: You also need to be adding the array to the arraylist inside the for loop, otherwise you're adding a null array.

```
for (int i=0; i<aArray.length-1; i++){
    exp=new int[100];
    if (Character.isDigit(aArray[i])){
        if(Character.isDigit(aArray[i])==true &&  aArray[i-1]=='-'){
            exp[j]=Character.getNumericValue(-(aArray[i]));
        }
        else{
            exp[j]=Character.getNumericValue(aArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.print(exp[j]);

        j++;   
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    list.add(exp);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I still get zeros.
when I print the exp array, I get the proper values, but when I try to do it with ArrayList, all I get is 0.

Comment: thanks. now I have another problem.
whatever "i" I give in list.get(i), I get the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved guys, I just needed to initialize exp array outside "for" loop, place a "while" loop and that's all!
Thank you for your answers!